# No primary interface in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: debian, networking

I am on Debian 9 and want to set up a static ip address. Following [this guide](https://jima.cat/from-dhcp-to-static-ip-on-ubuntu-server/) I should find a line beginning with `auto eth0` in `/etc/network/interfaces`, but there is no such thing here. Are these things changed in Debian 9? From `ip a` my network interface is `wlo1` - or this is just a loopback device?

```
root@emerald:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
root@emerald:~# ls /etc/network/interfaces.d/
root@emerald:~#
```

Output of `ip a`:

```
root@emerald:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ec:9a:74:f3:72:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:de:2b:9f:23:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlo1
       valid_lft 86377sec preferred_lft 86377sec
    inet6 fe80::76de:2bff:fe9f:2390/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: `wlo1` is your wifi interface , please add the output of `ip a`.

Comment: Added `ip a` output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since 2009 a `Consistent Network Device Naming` convention was adopted for naming `Ethernet adapters` in `Linux`, that's why you have `eno1` and not `eth0`. And for lacking a configuration for your main NIC in `/etc/networks/interfaces` - this is most likely because you have `network-manager` installed. You can see some information about it [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager).

If you want to use `/etc/network/intefaces`, simply disable or remove `Network-Manager` and configure `eno1` by your requirements in `/etc/network/interfaces`.